# Does a server need to be initialize for memcache

Tags: php, memcached

I have LAMP on my Mac Mountain Lion. My PHP was working fine. Then after restarting, it does not work until I run the following command in my terminal.

Do I have to run it all the time after restarting my laptop?

```
memcached -d -m 24 -p 11211
telnet localhost 11211
stats
quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you want to use memcached, then memcached has to be running...

Comment: Which line do I need to run in order to initialize?

Comment: Some experimentation would show you that `memcached -d -m 24 -p 11211` is the key here.

Answer (score 0):

Not too familiar with OSX, try to make it a startupitem, which should make it run on boot.
http://www.macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2003/10/21/startup.html